# Are there stereotypical speech patterns or inflections associated with gay Japanese speakers?

Tags: culture, gender

**This is not intended to be a controversial or provocative question.**

In English, there are ["commonly accepted" stereotypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay_lisp) for how gay people sometimes speak. Are there corresponding characteristics to how gay Japanese people speak, either specific words, phrases, or constructs; or in how certain sounds are inflected?

I'm curious if Japanese is as permissive as English in "allowing," for example, gay men to use more feminine speech forms, or if the strictures of the language and culture pretty much tie all genders to prescribed speech patterns regardless of sexual orientation.

Examples of words, phrases, or sentences that are clearly recognized as "gay" would be appreciated. For example, in the US, it is not uncommon for some gay men to call each other "girl." As another example, per the link above, sometimes gay men (especially when speaking excitably) have a distinctly melodic or tonal-variadic inflection. Things like this that might parallel to Japanese (or completely unique instances) are what I'm curious about.

Comment: IMHO the more flaming a guy is, esp in drag scenes (which are not always gay yes but esp in gay drag scenes) the more "hyper-fem" his speech gets. As much in Japanese as in English if not more so. There is a ton of gay slang as well. For reference there are a lot of gay and drag celebs on Japanese TV see  comedian Tanoshingo, Matusko Deluxe, Mitsu Mangrove, etc.

Comment: Matsuko Deluxe/Mitsu Mangrove are transvestite men (not necessarily homosexual) and speak very manlike. Tanoshingo and "Chris" Matsumura identify as homosexual and definitely do speak in a stereotypical fashion that to my ear seems quite similar to English. Here is [Chris Matsumura](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeXoKS3aP5s) and here is [Tanoshingo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kai0zMnFh9U) on youtube.

Comment: @jmac, I addressed that in my comment, but both Matsuko and Mitsu are gay transvestites/crossdressers. And though Mitsu speaks in a masculine tone I have assuredly heard him use feminine patterns.

Comment: @jmac, something similar can be said for Matsuko DX. Her voice might be masculine, but her speech patterns are definitely feminine, although not the childish-feminine type, but more the bossy-lady type.

Answer (score 1):

There's something called [オネエ言葉](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%8D%E3%82%A8%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89), which, similar to English, is a stereotype of gay men who use feminine speech/gestures.  c.f. [this show](http://www.ntv.co.jp/one-mans/) (warning: do not click if you are allergic to pink).

オネエ can be used to describe a person who uses such speech/gestures.